# MVC 3 with multiple database connection and web.config application settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know how to get an MVC 3 application with Entity Framework working with multiple database connections and multiple web.config appSettings?

Comment: Do you need multiple web.configs for multiple connection-strings?

Comment: what's your problem exactly? you can have multiple connection strings and appSettings values in your web.config

Comment: The problem I am having is  I need 7 multiple websites. But the logic building is same.  But I need to have 7 different database.   What I am trying to achieve is  EG. www.websitename.com/site1 , www.websitename.com/site2 .. etc...  But remember when I release the site, there will be one core code only.   So when I type site1, the site should read site1 database .  When I type site2, the site should read site2 database.  Is that making sense ?

Comment: @YairNevet I need one website using different database to browse different website.  EG. www.sitename.com/site1, www.sitename.com/site2

Comment: @coder Please look at my answer and see if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the sub-folders (site1, site2 etc.) are virtual directories or controllers names, you're able to use theirs names for different connection-strings.

Use multiple connection-strings in only one web.config file and retrieve them by the requested URL virtual directory name (naming convention-based).

At web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="site1" connectionString="data source=BLAHBLAH1" />
    <add name="site2" connectionString="data source=BLAHBLAH2" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and in the code:

```
using System.Configuration;
...
var currentLocationName = HttpRequest.ApplicationPath; // "site1, site2 etc."
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[currentLocationName].ConnectionString;
//set the correct connection string for your objectContext (Entity Framework)
return new Entities(conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 7 websites you also have 7 web.config files - each will point to correct database.

Comment: He have only one website and he want it to be generic enough to host different data.